# Failed to register a ServiceWorker - Angular, Express

Tags: angular, express, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am serving my angular app via an Express server in HTTPS (for PWA enablement). In my development environment, I am able to get PWA with the same Server and angular code. But in higher environment receiving error like this

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AbortError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy/') with script ('https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy/ngsw-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
 at O (polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1)
    at polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1
    at polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.e1811227a8dd47dc4199.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1)
    at polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.d1c7bf4a2ae7c3435f95.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.e1811227a8dd47dc4199.js:1)
```

Comment: What is a `higher environment`?

Comment: In Virtual machine (Cloud) I am running the code. The site is running but PWA is not. @Carsten

Comment: In my dist folder all the files ngsw.json, ngsw-worker.js, manifest.json are there @Carsten

Comment: Does your PWA when running with your HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Since I am using Self Signed Certificate, I am getting that error it seems. I will try by adding a valid certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using Self Signed Certificate, I received that error. After adding a valid certificate it is working as expected.